# Changed to Google Sign and now I don't know how to sign my app

Tags: android

It's been two years since I've updated my app.

I've fixed the stuff that I need to fix, because I want new people to actually be able to install it in newer devices (all personal acquaintances). I care not for monetization. I just want simple distribution. I never plan in adding any new features to it either. Keep this in mind.

I have the old KeyStore that I originally signed my app with and all the passwords written down.

But they don't work. No matter what I try command, sign, keytool, Key Explorer or otherwise I inevitably run into this error upon providing the password for the key itself:

"java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key"

So having no other options I selected to upgrade my app signing key to be signed by Google. An option I apparently can do only once a year. I selected this option because It was the recommend option. I clearly messed up.

I created a new KeyStore. And I was able to generate a signed bundle.

When I try to upload the signed bundle it tells me that

"Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your App Bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with fingerprint:"

Which makes sense as Google knows nothing about the newly created key.

And If I try to upload an unsigned bundle it tells me the bundle is not signed (I thought google itself would sign it, and I clearly was wrong).

Is there any simple solution to my problem?

If not, is it possible to simply "start over" and delete my app from the store and generate a new one so that I can finally publish it?